# DropNet Integration - GetAccessTokenAsync error

Tags: c#, windows-phone, dropbox-api, dropnet

I'm trying to implement the [DropNet library](http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/) into my Windows Phone app but I'm getting the an error when calling the `GetAccessTokenAsync` method.

**Step 1: Get the oauth token from Dropbox**

```
public void ConnectToDropbox()
{
    _client = new DropNetClient(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
    _client.UseSandbox = true;

    // Get Request Token (oauth token) from Dropbox
    _client.GetTokenAsync(
        (userLogin) =>
        {
            // Authorise app with Dropbox
            var url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
            browser.LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(browser_LoadCompleted);
            browser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            Debug("Error: GetTokenAsync");
        });

}
```

This seems to work correctly and returns an oauth authorisation code. The URL which the browser navigates to is
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=TSLEY7lLS8K2Mmnr

**Step 2: Convert the oauth token into usable Dropbox API token**

```
void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Debug("Callback URL: " + e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    if (e.Uri.AbsolutePath == "/1/oauth/authorize")
    {

        //The User has logged in!
        //Now to convert the Request Token into an Access Token
        _client.GetAccessTokenAsync(
            (response) =>
            {
                Debug("User is logged in");
                LoadContents();
            },
                (error) =>
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        Debug("Error getting access token (GetAccessTokenAsync)");
                        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                    });
                });
    }
    else
    {
        //Probably the login page loading, ignore
    }
}
```

The `GetAccessTokenAsync` method throws the following exceptions at runtime:

*An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary*

The in-app MessageBox displays:
*Exception of type 'DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException' was thrown.*

All the properties of the DropboxException object are as follows:

**Response:**   RestSharp.RestResponse

**Status Code:**    Unauthorized

**Stack Trace:**

**Data:**           System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

**Base Exception:** DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException: Exception of type 'DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException' was thrown.

**Inner Exception:**

**Type:**   DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException

Is the the Status Code *Unauthorized* relevant? I'm using the appropriate API key and secret provdided by Dropbox.

I'd be grateful if anyone who's experienced similar issues when using DropNet could give me some advice in resolving this problem. Happy to provide any further info if needed.

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: Have you looked at the Response property of the DropboxException object? It might provide some insight for you.

Comment: I've edited the original post and included the DropboxException properties. It looks like the **RestSharp.RestResponse** is returning with a status code of **Unauthorized**.

Comment: Do you get any content in the RestResponse explaining what the problem  is?

Comment: No, there's no further content in RestResponse. I'm starting to wonder if the problem is in the `GetTokenAsync` method.  The `BuildAuthorizeURL` method returns the URL:  
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Yopwrkzfd41fpHV1  

Is this correct or should the URL also contain an oauth_secret segment?

Comment: I think you are calling the GetAccessToken function too early as you have this line: `if (e.Uri.AbsolutePath == "/1/oauth/authorize")` which is checking for the authorize page where the user allows access to the app (after logging in) which you need to wait for then get the access token. Try using a callback Url here and checking for that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I created a new Visual Studio solution and rewrote all the code and it's now working perfectly.  DropNet seems like a great library.  I'll post my app on your website once it's finished.